# To dispaly Custom Text when no records are found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQ Code. I want to check if user has deleted all records then JQ Should display as- NO RECORDS.

```js
function Delete(altId) {  
           var ctrlDeleteId = '.deleteAl' + alertId.toString();  
           if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?')) {  
               $.post('Update.ashx', { AltId: altId, actionType: 'delete' }, function (data) {  
                   if (data === 'Success') {  
                       $(ctrlDeleteId).closest("tr").hide(300, function () { $target.remove(); });  
                   }  
               });  
           }  
       };
```

Thanks,

Comment: `if(records.length == 0){ /* "NO RECORDS" */ }`

Comment: share your html code here

Comment: html goes here -  <a class="deleteAlt<%#Eval("AltId") %>" href="Javascript: DeleteAlt('<%#Eval("AltId") %>');">Delete</a> @geekbro

Comment: no success after adding that piece @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: @MS_RPS That's just to give you a general idea of what to do logically because there is no information provided to answer this question. You didn't provide any data on the records in question, nor information on where to display this message. How could we answer with such information?